# Android: Dealing with Vertical Images in a Horizontal imageview, Picasso

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso

So I'm working on a project thats pulling images down through a API (I have no control over the images on the server). Roughly 90% of the images are horizontal (Width > Height), and 10% of the images are vertical (Height > Width).

I have a horizontal image view that i'm trying to put the images into. I am required to use Picasso to load the images in to the imageview. Currently I am using centerCrop() so on 90% of the images the images look nice in the imageview because both the image and imageview are horizontal so minimal cropping is done. But with roughly 10% of the images they are vertical so when I put them into a horizontal imageview about half the image gets cropped (Top and bottom) because it's centerCrop(). This looks absolutely terrible because too much of the image is cropped out.

I'm wondering what the best way to deal with a situation like this. I've look all over the internet looking for answers like a transform() but I'm not quite sure if that's the right answer. Changing the imageview to a square or other shape is not possible. It must take up the entire phones width and the height takes up roughly 40% of the height. Using fitXY doesn't look good either because the vertical images get skewed out of aspect ratio too much and it looks funky.

Comment: How about centerFit?

Comment: centerFit leaves empty space on the left and right with vertical images. The image must be the entire width of the screen. I'd imagine I'd have to like skrink the height of vertical images and then centerCrop or something so I retain a little more image. But I'm not really sure how I could go about doing that for only vertical images.

Comment: Oh. I am not sure about that. Nevertheless I'll still check. See I am not sure if this is possible because  even the gallery can't do this

Comment: Would it be ok if it like got rotated? Because I don't understand how u could load a vertical image inside a horizontal view without distorting it

Comment: Unfortunately rotating is not an option. The images are of a landscape so idk. I assume people run into this issue every once and awhile and they would have a solution but maybe not. I know it'd seem almost impossible to not distort it but who knows. That why I was wondering if people had solutions for it.

Comment: Well, I am sorry because I don't know if there is ANYWAY to do it without either rotating, distorting or clipping/cropping the image. I don't know if this is possible. But I recommend you post this question in SuperUser as well. Not like a programming question; but simply asking for some logic.

Comment: Alright, Will do. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't help you